# bind to entrybox and change the input

Tags: python-3.x, events, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to change the inputs in the entryboxes with an eventbindfunction, like when the user hits the tabkey, the input changes automatically to capitalletters OR when he leaves with the mouse pointer.
How can i fix this?Do I need to bind every entrybox seperatly?
Thank you for helping me.
I appreciate  your kindness!

```
from tkinter import*
window=Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

window.title("Lowwerletters")
heading = Label(text="smaller", bg="grey", fg="black", width="500", height="3")
heading.pack()

def onreturn():
firstname_info=firstname.get()
s=firstname_info.lower()
t=lastname_info.lower()
firstname_entry.insert(str(0,s))
lastname_entry.insert(str(0,t))

firstname_text = Label(text="firstname")
lastname_text=Label(text="lastname")

firstname_text.place(x=15, y=55)
lastname_text.place(x=15, y=85)

firstname_entry =Entry(textvariable=firstname,width="40")
firstname_entry.bind("Tab",onreturn)
lastname_entry=Entry(textvariable=lastname,width="40")

firstname_entry.place(x=80,y=55)
lastname_entry.place(x=85,y=85)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The question you asked can be answered with available documentation. It doesn't appear you've even tried to solve the problem, so it's not clear what you need help with.

Comment: @BryanOakley I changed the code with my attempt to solve it.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. It's not clear how much of the code is inside the `onreturn` function.